# Problem in Shading in ListPlot

Tags: plotting

I want to shade the region in the right/Left side of a vertical line with gray colour in ListPlot. For example I write a code like this:

```
abc = {{0.98, 0}, {0.98, 6}, {0.98, 15}};
ListPlot[{abc}  , Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{0.6, 1}, {0, 10}}, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, 
 BaseStyle -> Directive[Bold, FontFamily -> "Times", 18], 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], ImageSize -> 400, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Black, DotDashed, Thick]}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Axes -> False, Filling -> Axis]
```

But I get the plot like this-[image]

So, I need help to shade the area in left or right side of this vertical straight line with gray colour.

Comment: Something like this: `ListPlot[{{0., 0.}, {0.3, 0.6}, {0.7, 0.4}, {0.9, 0.3}, {0.99, 0.1}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.05], Prolog -> {{Opacity[0.7, Gray], HalfPlane[{0.95, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}]}, {Directive[Black, DotDashed, Thick], InfiniteLine[{0.95, 0}, {0, 1}]}}]`?

Comment: Thanks, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use "Epilog" to shade these regions. E.g.:

```
ListPlot[{abc, {{0.6, 0}, {0.6, 10}}}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.6, 1}, {0, 10}}, PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, 
 BaseStyle -> Directive[Bold, FontFamily -> "Times", 18], 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], ImageSize -> 400, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Black, DotDashed, Thick]}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Axes -> False, 
 Epilog -> {Opacity[0.5], LightGray, Rectangle[{0.6, 0}, {0.98, 10}], 
   Gray, Rectangle[{0.98, 0}, {1, 10}]}]
```

[image]